# Python function ends in hung program

Tags: python, pycharm

I am very new to programming and python.  I am trying to use this code:

```
def show_cards(hand):
    for c in hand:
        b = "[" + c + "]"
        hand.append(b)


a = ["a","b","c","d"]

show_cards(a)

print(a)
```

however, whenever I do so, the program just hangs. I thought maybe it was my editor(pycharm) but I've tried running it in just the terminal as well and it's the same result.

actually, I should note, in pycharm I get a keyboard interrupt error that flashes for a second then goes away. I do not get this in the terminal.

I have tried just writing it out in a for loop and forgoing the function, but it's the same issue.

I don't see anything that would cause this and I get no errors, just a hung program.

Any help is appreciated!

Also, I'm sure there is an easier way to write this, so a push in the right direction there would be great as well!!

Comment: You're making `hand` longer as you iterate through it, so you never get to the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*list.[append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)(x)* adds the item 'x' to the end of the list. Your code iterates through the list 'hand,' but each time it does so it adds a new item to the end of the list. Thus, the list will never end, so neither will your `for` loop.

Regarding an easier way to write this, it depends what you're trying to accomplish. If what you want is a list with the same items in square brackets, you might try something like this:

```
def show_cards(hand):
    new_list = []
    for c in hand:
        b = "[" + c + "]"
        new_list.append(b)
    return(new_list)
```

The *[return](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/return.html)()* statement allows the function to produce a new list, which you can then assign to  the variable `a` like this:

```
a = show_cards(a)
```

Alternately, you can change the items in your list `a` directly, without calling a separate function, by using *[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)()*. The `enumerate()` function returns a list of tuples, each of which contains the index of an item in the last (starting with 0, the index of the first item) and its value. So `enumerate(a)` returns:

```
[(0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "d"), (4, "e")]
```

Which means you can replace each of the items in your list `a` like this:

```
for index, value in enumerate(a):
    a[index] = "[" + value + "]"
```

And then the value of list `a` should be:

```
["[a]", "[b]", "[c]", "[d]", "[e]"]
```

If that's not what you wanted, let us know.

Comment: best first post in months!

Comment: Great explanation, thank you.  I'm annoyed at how obvious it is now!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an infinite loop by appending to `hand` within the loop.

Try something like this to print the hand with braquets:

```
def show_cards(hand):
    for c in hand:
        print("[" + c + "]")
```

You can also append to a string and return it if you'd like.